# Clean up shards from previous elasticsearch version (5.4 -> 5.6)

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, sharding, elasticsearch-5

**Rolling Upgrade**

Following the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/rolling-upgrades.html), I upgraded an elasticsearch cluster from version 5.4 to version 5.6.

This process caused the disk usage on each upgraded node to double.

The following documentation made me assume that this problem would be rectified once the entire cluster was upgraded:

> During a rolling upgrade the cluster will continue to operate as normal. Any new functionality will be disabled or work in a backward compatible manner until all nodes of the cluster have been upgraded. Once the upgrade is completed and all nodes are on the new version, the new functionality will become operational. Once that has happened, it is practically impossible to go back to operating in a backward compatible mode. To protect against such a scenario, nodes from the previous major version (e.g. 5.x) will not be allowed to join a cluster where all nodes are of a higher major version (e.g. 6.x).

**Disk Usage Doubled**

However, even once every node in the cluster was the same version (`5.6.16`), each node that held previous data continues to hold onto that data, and the cluster does not clean it up. This means the disk usage has effectively doubled, and I've had to modify the `high/low watermark` values simply to allow cluster operation to continue.

I do not understand the internals of elasticsearch's data well enough to know what directories need to be deleted and which ones should be kept. Perhaps there is even a built-in way to force the cleanup.

**Small example from the data directory:**

```
$ ls nodes/0/indices/
-AW6zio6TuynJ_KQlEooVA  66O4EMc0R3KYclO50uRQ1g  CuiQlU_dTDOVkJbV9oQIGw  J_YG4HlBRYeBWp0wc0L_Nw  Qw-3eYh6TlGpHCys2GBdwg  YRrQono1QCWxXahJIT0hfg  eK0di6WSRnumTUHiqAQ3gw  m3EDPIOqS9mx22k6hQH2yA  umpdodA2QR6de8VcuR3qag
-ItvQ5StRECde2zvdV-Ucg  6FAopyspSLu8NGEUekOwhg  CzqDKml3QCG16g0zxgnG7g  JgbfkCt5RDGmpFowxnYIiA  QwerlX68SaqhEzg-Ml3i0Q  YcbvcSuxQtaNIXcxU6mpJQ  eOww30E7R96ymTqhQyNYng  mAspUVrETLuAP6zapD8IVQ  uoMcWwmfTeCTKXchAyVt-w
-K59oANFSmmopPt2r5yjYg  6GWAf6ITT4e_9HNwjYlk3g  D3Co7Ht1SROlEGCHcSn67Q  JrSXkDEETfS8XHe-PH-9qw  RB6LxG9uT_eW8Z28Zh4b9A  YjHJMVZjRK-8Coya8eBMOA  eVtK6_HrTA-1yAfDEnKZnw  mG_NCeR3RhSQO6tLRYmJGg  upHl_Bu7R0eFZUxU5qrDrA
-WevSR0jRZKTz7CH5LWKOQ  6L6MDgW0QCWLn0lr6NwRUA  DEB0-vP7TMmyBK8M18sJ2A  JtXS6yJPQwGKhC0qAulNBQ  RKcX1apNTsyod54oLYnJ0A  YuLmawshTn-WCPPD8Hs8YA  ecrbXDCdSleo6Y2_p6SDeg  mHOr6_WMT4ODxBGh1e5MCw  uq9BlreyTk-xXM-HTsmesw
-jjL_BjFTFycO83wVW4L6Q  6LD31skNSbGVgscF784PnQ  DG1ESvHdS1y8AzbbqhML6Q  Ju6ks-W5Q4yX0GggfO3hQw  RKcvj2kwRe6OBspnZBFrjA  Yuu9nCSfTjCqEwcznS1Oqw  eq6QwBMaTI2fik81gyD6gQ  mKXR0uWtTjenFFkq0GVP8g  utoyyWn3SY23rKrg8sCwpg
-t4M8dc9TZiKYZI7Mia8hQ  6Rw8yFOhSvqveDoWf19F5A  DOJaKVahTvm7G79RIfpGhQ  K-a5KU8hT-WSQw1cPAWXhw  RPhKOIYNRoKQYHPauPpYzQ  Z0GgoShfR2iGidFa-fXhzQ  f8qpQPOARdeqHcXH3OFBqQ  mM_43p8mRsOCosUH2C3iUg  uv40fHgkQtCFShozCAmtMQ
04JbWXE4S-66wTVQZ6587Q  6XjX8cP1QEuCxalGCmq9bQ  Dc-lhr15Qz6sCEdw4smRGQ  KAHIxqC2Sm-8Cu-fo4P54A  Rd6gkNVkTxitNvGPtmJ8jw  Z6c02QTLRz6nrfVEjMQr3g  fPJyBMlVQQ2j5oyvyYQKNw  mUioLd-hTq2CbRpQ6BMfxw  vC3erzIcT1Ked9vGmCGRFw
```

How can I clean up the old shards created by version 5.4?

Comment: You start with the idea that something is broken in Elasticsearch and data needs cleaning up, but to dig into the reasons why disk usage may appear as to have doubled, some patience is recommended and cluster stats info need to be looked at in detail (and probably other bits of information as well). May I suggest following up on the discuss forum post where David has some unanswered questions in his latest post there? He's one of the best persons to help you with such issues. But you need to be patient and provide answers to all his questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to determine a root cause or mechanism to handle the doubling of the disk usage, and so instead I re-indexed the entire cluster into a new 7.x cluster over the course of about a month. Once complete, I removed the old cluster from the servers it occupied and added those servers to the new cluster, which automatically set about rebalancing things.

This took quite some time but ended up being an effective route. I did not see unusual disk usage by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand the internals of elasticsearch's data well enough to know what directories need to be deleted and which ones should be kept.

They should all be kept. **You should never manually alter the contents of the data directory.**

There is no difference between 5.4 shards and 5.6 ones, so there is no extra manual cleanup required here. The documentation you quote pertains to upgrades across major versions (e.g. 5.x to 6.x) and does not apply to minor upgrades (e.g. 5.4 to 5.6). If the shards were assigned to new nodes during the restart then Elasticsearch will have temporarily made an extra copy of some replicas, but it will clean up any old copies that it no longer needs when those shards' health is `green` and none of them are relocating.

If your cluster health is green and contains no relocating shards but the disk usage hasn't dropped down to what you expect then I suggest you use the stats APIs (e.g. [`GET /index/_stats?level=shards`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) to try and work out which indices are consuming all the space. If you need help analysing these stats then please [start a conversation on the discussion forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/c/elasticsearch) as it is awkward to hold that kind of conversation here.

Comment: Link to discussion topic: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cluster-upgrade-from-5-4-5-6-doubled-disk-usage/212539